# Even function integration problem

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be an even function.  Show
$$\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=2\int_0^af(x)dx$$
So I thought of breaking it up into two integtrals with one from $-a$ to $0$ and $0$ to $a$.  Then I have on the left side
$$\int_{-a}^0f(x)dx$$
Then I thought

$$\int_{-a}^0f(x)dx=-\int_0^{-a}f(x)dx=-\int_0^{-(-a)}f(-x)dx$$ but this seems wrong.  Where am I mistaken?

Comment: If $x=-y$, then $dx = -dy$?

Comment: Soooo close.  Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the substitution $y=-x, dy=-dx$ in the $\int_{-a}^0 f(x)dx$.  This turns it into $\int_0^a f(-y)dy=\int_0^a f(y)dy=\int_0^a f(x)dx$.

Comment: $\mathrm{d}y=-\mathrm{d}x$

Answer (score 2):

If you substitute $-x$ for $x$, you also need to substitute $\mathrm{d}(-x)=-\mathrm{d}x$. The two negatives cancel each other out.