# Proof $ \int_{-a}^a \, f\left(x^2\right) \, dx = 2\int_{0}^a f\left(x^2\right) \, dx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to prove $ \int_{-a}^a \, f\left(x^2\right) \, dx = 2\int_{0}^a f\left(x^2\right) \, dx $, assuming the integral on the LHS of the equation exists. Is my proof valid?

Let $ g\left(x\right) = f\left(x^2\right) $ and let $  D = \left[-a, a\right] $. Therefore, for all $ x \in D\, $:

$$ g\left(x\right) = f\left(x^2\right)$$

$$ g\left(-x\right) = f\left(\left(-x\right)^2\right) = f\left(x^2\right) $$

Therefore, $ g(x) $ is even. Therefore, the $ \int_{0}^a \, g\left(x\right) \, dx = \int_{-a}^0 \, g\left(x\right) \, dx $. $ \,\int_{-a}^a \, g\left(x\right) \, dx = \int_{-a}^0 \, g\left(x\right) \, dx \, + \, \int_{0}^a \, g\left(x\right) \, dx \Rightarrow \int_{-a}^a \, g\left(x\right) \, dx = 2 \int_{0}^a g\left(x\right) \, dx $

Comment: what if $ f(x)=\sqrt(x)$

Comment: Is $f$ a polynomial?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Not necessarily, maybe I forgot to mention that it's continuous on $ [-a, a] $

Comment: @JoseGarcia - Then $f(x^2) = |x|$?

Comment: In fact, $f(x^2)$ could be replaced with any even function.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Yeah, but I believe one of the "tricks" in the exercise was to realize $ f $ is even

Comment: @talopl - just to be pedantic, $f(x)$ isn't even, but $f(x^2)$ is. I'm sure you get that, I just wanted to stop others who may read this later from getting confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Even function integration problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526396/even-function-integration-problem) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B-a%7D%5E%7Ba%7Df%5Cleft(x%5E2%5Cright)dx%20%3D%202%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Ba%7Df%5Cleft(x%5E2%5Cright)dx%24&p=1). There are also other basically duplicate questions, e.g., [Definition of integrability](/q/3174347) and [Particular integrals question](/q/366412).

Comment: FYI, there's also other questions which ask about your particular problem plus to prove other things, e.g., to also prove that $\int_{-a}^{a}xf(x^2)dx = 0$ in [Proving these statements simply with Riemann integral definition](/q/2445070) and [If $f(x^2)$ is $\mathscr{R} [0,a]$, then prove $f(x^2)$ and $xf(x^2)$ are $\mathscr{R}[-a,a]$.](/q/2054876).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Your proof is valid. Since $g(x)$ is even and by changing the variable $x$ into $ t = -x$, we find:
$$\int_{-a}^0 g(x) dx = \int_{a}^0 -g(t) dt = \int_{0}^a g(t) dt$$
Remove the dummy variable to get:
$$\int_{-a}^0 g(x) dx = \int_{0}^a g(x) dx$$
And therefore, as you mentioned in your proof
$$\int_{-a}^a g(x) dx = 2 \int_{0}^a g(x) dx$$
which implies
$$\int_{-a}^a f(x^2) dx = 2 \int_{0}^a f(x^2) dx$$

Comment: I would do it slightly differently.$\int_{-a}^a f(x^2)dx= $\int_{-a}^0 f(x^2)dx+  \int_0^a f(x^2)dx$.